# Select values that don't occur in a table

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm sure this has been asked somewhere, but I found it difficult to search for.

If I want to get all records where a column value equals one in a list, I'd use the [`IN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) operator.

```
SELECT idSparePart, SparePartName 
  FROM tabSparePart 
  WHERE SparePartName IN (
      '1234-2043','1237-8026','1238-1036','1238-1039','1223-5172'
    )
```

Suppose this `SELECT` returns 4 rows although the list has 5 items. How can I select the value that does not occur in the table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you have it return as the fifth row if it isn't even in the table?

Comment: @Matti: I'm only interested in which `SparePartNames` are not in the table. Since i don't have more than the name it would be sufficient to get only the name(the ID-Column can be `null`).

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.* from (
    select '1234-2043' as sparePartName
    union select '1237-8026'
    union select '1238-1036'
    union select '1238-1039'
    union select '1223-5172'
) t
where not exists (
    select 1 from tabSparePart p WHERE p.SparePartName = t.sparePartName
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you mentioned that i have to create a temp table, i remembered my `Split`-function.

Sorry for answering my own question, but this might be the the best/simplest way for me:

```
SELECT PartNames.Item
FROM   dbo.Split('1234-2043,1237-8026,1238-1036,1238-1039,1223-5172', ',') AS PartNames  
       LEFT JOIN tabSparePart ON tabSparePart.SparePartName = PartNames.Item
WHERE idSparePart IS NULL
```

My `Split`-function:
[Help with a sql search query using a comma delimitted parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426499/help-with-a-sql-search-query-using-a-comma-delimitted-parameter/5426551#5426551)

Thank you all anyway.

Comment: <--UPVOTE...nice... same idea I was thinking of

Comment: Yup, me too. I think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I misunderstood the question.  I guess in that case I would select the values into a temp table, then select the values which are not in that table.  Not ideal, I know -- the problem is that you need to get your list of part names to SQL Server somehow (either via IN or putting them in a temp table) but the semantics of IN don't do what you want.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tabSparePart
(
    SparePartName  nvarchar(50)
)
insert into tabSparePart values('1234-2043')


CREATE TABLE #tempSparePartName
(
    SparePartName  nvarchar(50)
)
insert into #tempSparePartName values('1234-2043')
insert into #tempSparePartName values('1238-1036')
insert into #tempSparePartName values('1237-8026') 

select * from #tempSparePartName
where SparePartName not in (select SparePartName from tabSparePart)
```

With output:

```
SparePartName
1238-1036
1237-8026
```

Original (wrong) answer:
You can just use "`not in`":

```
SELECT * from tabSparePart WHERE SparePartName NOT in(
'1234-2043','1237-8026','1238-1036','1238-1039','1223-5172'
)
```

Comment: This will return all records in table that are not in the list. I want all items in list that are not in the table.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this....

```
declare @test as table
(
    items varchar(50)
)

insert into @test
    values('1234-2043')

insert into @test
    values('1234-2043')

insert into @test
    values('1237-8026') 

-- the rest of the values --

select * from @test
    where items not in (
        select theItemId from SparePartName 
        )
```

for fun check this out... 
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx

It shows you how to take delimited data and return it from a table valued function as separate "rows"... which my make the process of creating the table to select from easier than inserting into a @table or doing a giant select union subquery.

Comment: I hoped there would be a simpler way, because i'm often need this with a long list of items in SSMS.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: How do you pass this long list to the query?

Comment: Copy&Paste. I remembered my [`split`-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182348/select-not-existing-values-opposite-of-where-column-in1-2-3/8182721#8182721) that might be the simplest way for this, since i don't need to insert all those values in a temp-table manually.