# Execute stored procedure with array-like string separated by comma

Tags: c#, .net, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help with a sql search query using a comma delimitted parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426499/help-with-a-sql-search-query-using-a-comma-delimitted-parameter)

I want to write a stored procedure that performs a select on a table and need one input variable of type `varchar(max)`.

I'd like to send a bunch of values separated by `,` as the input parameter, e.g.

```
'Jack','Jane','Joe'
```

and then get the rows that contain one of these names.

In SQL the code would be

```
Select * from Personnel where Name in ('Jack','Joe','Jane');
```

Now I want to have a variable in my C# app, say strNames and fill it like

```
string strNames = "'Jack','Joe','Jane'";
```

and send this variable to the SP and execute it. Something like

```
Select * from Personnel where Name in (''Jack','Joe','Jane'') -- this is wrong
```

But **how can I tell SQL Server to run such command?**

I need to make this happen and I know it's possible, please give me the clue.

Comment: Is is possible to send for example this string `Select * from Table1` to a stored procedure and the sp executes it as a command? I somehow want sql to execute a string.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but I'd never EVER do that.

Comment: Oops because it's vulnerable? or other reasons? I'm curious

Comment: Vulnerability is one thing. You also lose all comfort provided by the .NET framework, for example the fact that parameters are always passed to the query in the right format, etc. (think of i18 issues for date or floating point values). Also, if you want to send the statement to a stored procedure, you could as well right away execute it in your application - what's the difference?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I seeeeeeee ... got the point, thanks.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: it's either i18n, or i19 :)

Comment: Mahdi.  You can do that with the sp_executesql command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx  It does have it's place.  But you need to be very cautious using it.  My main concern would be around making sure you are not "building" your sql command using user input, and hence sql-injection.

Comment: @SWeko Ar yo sur? :-D Of course you're right. Typo, too late for editing...

Comment: This has been asked [numerous times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+comma+parameter), e.g. [Help with a sql search query using a comma delimitted parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426499/help-with-a-sql-search-query-using-a-comma-delimitted-parameter)

Comment: @Pondlife: Asking how to bind comma-separated parameters in C#'s SQL Server interface is not the same as asking how to split a string in a SQL Server stored procedure. So, while I think this probably _is_ a duplicate of something, I don't think it's a duplicate of the question you linked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the single names don't need to be quoted when you pass them to the stored procedure.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longFilter", "Jack,Jill,Joe");

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in the stored procedure, you can use simple text functions and a temporary table as follows to split up the string at the commas and an an entry to the temporary table for each part of the string:

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(255))

IF ISNULL(@longFilter, '') <> ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(max)
    WHILE LEN(@longFilter) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF CHARINDEX(',', @longFilter) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @s = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@longFilter, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @longFilter) - 1)))
            SET @longFilter = SUBSTRING(@longFilter, CHARINDEX(',', @longFilter) + 1, LEN(@longFilter))
        END ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @s = LTRIM(RTRIM(@longFilter))
            SET @longFilter= ''
        END

        -- This was missing until 20140522
        INSERT INTO @temp (Name) VALUES (@s)
    END
END
```

Later use the following `SELECT` to get a list of all people the name of which is in `@temp` or all of them if `@temp` doesn't contain any rows (unfiltered result):

```
SELECT * FROM Personnel WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM @temp) OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp) = 0
```

Comment: How does this work? It doesn't look like the longFilter values are ever getting stored in the temp table. Is some of the SQL code missing? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Actually, you're right (funny nobody noticed it before) - the actual INSERT into the temp table was missing. I added it with a comment. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Basically, you could insert a list of values as a parameter in the procedure, and use them as a table, something along the lines of

```
Select * from Personnel 
  where Name in (select name from @NamesTable).
```

Now, the specifics

- To use table valued parameters, the type of the parameter must be predefined in sql server, using

  ```
  create type NamesTable as table (Name varchar(50))
  ```
- You can then use the defined type as a parameter in the procedure

  ```
  create procedure getPersonnelList
    @NamesTable NamesTable readonly
  as
  begin
    select * from personnel
      where Name in (select Name from @NamesTable)
  end
  ```

  You can see that in action, in [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b372e/1)
- On the C# side of things you need to create the parameter. If you have the names in a collection, and build the string, you can just use that to generate the parameter, and if they are a comma-separated string, a quick `string.Split` could take care of that. Since I do not know your specifics, I'll assume you have a `List<string>` called `names`. You'll need to convert that to a table valued parameter to be sent to the procedure, using something like:

  ```
  DataTable tvparameter = new DataTable();
  tvparameter.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  foreach (string name in names)
  {
    tvparameter.Rows.Add(name);
  }
  ```

  You can find more info on how to generate a TVP in C# code in the [SO Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code).
- Now you just need to send that parameter to the procedure, and that's that. Here is a complete console program that executes the procedure and outputs the results.

  ```
  List<string> names = new List<string> { "Joe", "Jane", "Jack" };

  using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("..."))
  {
    cnn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getPersonnelList", cnn))
    {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      DataTable tvparameter = new DataTable();
      tvparameter.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
      foreach (string name in names)
      {
        tvparameter.Rows.Add(name);
      }

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NamesTable", tvparameter);

      using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
          Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", dr["ID"], dr["Name"]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need Split Function in Sql Server to break Comma-Separated Strings into Table. Please refer these links.

[Split Function in Sql Server to break Comma-Separated Strings into Table](http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx)

[SQL User Defined Function to Parse a Delimited String](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str)

You can select the data from table using

```
Select * from 
Personnel where 
  Name in (select items from dbo.Split ('Jack,Joe,Jane',','))
```

Comment: The "best" function I know for this purpose can be found at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Answer (score 2):

You could simply check if Name is contained in the string. Note the commas at the start of the end to ensure you match the full name

```
string strNames = ",Jack,Joe,Jane,";
```

The the SQL becomes

```
select * from Personnel where PATINDEX('%,' + Name + ',%', @strNames) > 0
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ee5a/1