# SQL Where clause with dynamic IN() operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I have a query which should be later used to build an SSRS-2008 report.
This query is going to be used as a generic template for many reports.

Because of that, the query have lots of parameters in it, and each report should configure the parameters accordingly in the Report Builder.

After this long intro, my issue is that:

In the query's `WHERE` clause the parameters are with `IN()` operator, for example:

```
WHERE Users IN(@p1) AND ...
```

the `@p1` in one report can be specific users (e.g. `WHERE Users IN(121,154,151)` ), and in different report it can be **all users** . In that case ,**and this is my question**, what is the value that the parameter `@p1` should get ?

I know I can use different data set in order to retrieve all the users and put it in the parameter, but I want to avoid that (due to performance issues and keep the query as generic as possible) and want to know if there is any other options ? (something like `IN('% %')` )

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I like your picture which is full of love and wish you a happy life.

After that you may find [This same question of mine about list-like parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14257355/1471381) useful, I asked it a couple of days ago and came up with pretty nice and various solutions.

hope it helps.

Comment: First I want to thank you for your compliments, and also to wish you a lovely and a happy life too. this photo were taken from our wedding last year. About the question - thanks I think I found what I was looking for. Gil

Comment: @GilPeretz I'm happy to have found a new friend from a new spot of the world. Mahdi

Comment: Same here, nice to meet you mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just changing the parameters

```
  @p1 = "SELECT users FROM table"
```

Comment: I don't deal with the parameter in the query, only in the report builder. In addition I wish not to use another table (users table), only the table in the main query.